# How to solve Firebase invalid api key error

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I`m using firebase for a React project, however I'm getting this invalid-api-key error.

My config file looks like this:

```
    const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "**********************",
    authDomain: "******.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "*******",
    storageBucket: "********.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "*********************",
    appId: "1:***************************"
  };
```

and I initialize firebase like this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import { firebaseConfig } from "../firebaseConfig";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  firebaseConfig
});

console.log(firebase.default.auth);

export const auth = app.auth();
export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  firebaseConfig
});
```

you are actually calling (using [object initialization shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions)):

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "**********************",
    authDomain: "******.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "*******",
    storageBucket: "********.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "*********************",
    appId: "1:***************************"
  }
});
```

This means that `firstArg.apiKey` is `undefined` and leads to the error you see.

You should be passing the object itself instead:

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

or a copy of it if you want (using [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)):

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp({ ...firebaseConfig });
```